# Is the Goblin keeping my door closed?

Tags: timber-and-stone

I killed a goblin marauder directly outside my fortress door, which is great, except now my units will not exit the fort (this is the only entrance).  Is the corpse the problem, and what can I do to solve the problem?

[image: Goblin Marauder in front of the door - screenshot]

Comment: There are still many bugs in the game as it is only 1.0 version. Take this as an example and post this on the Timber and Stone website as a bug report. http://timberandstone.com/

Comment: @jacen.garriss Only 1.0?  *sigh* Well, I'll post a bug when the website gets back up.

Answer (score 2):

Right clicking on the corpse gives the option to `Remove Corpse` which again allowed my units to leave the fortress.

So yes, a dead unit currently blocks doors.  I've seen this with other enemies in more recent versions (1.41) as well.